# How to get particular value in the object(WC_Cart) in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, cart

I have The `WC()->cart` object that has this structure:

```
object(WC_Cart)#803 (13) {
  ["cart_contents"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["e369853df766fa44e1ed0ff613f563bd"]=>
    array(11) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(32) "e369853df766fa44e1ed0ff613f563bd"
      ["product_id"]=>
      int(34)
      ["variation_id"]=>
      int(0)
      ["variation"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["quantity"]=>
      int(1)
      ["line_tax_data"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["subtotal"]=>
        array(1) {
          [1]=>
          float(31.5)
        }
        ["total"]=>
        array(1) {
          [1]=>
          float(31.5)
        }
      }
      ["line_subtotal"]=>
      float(150)
      ["line_subtotal_tax"]=>
      float(31.5)
      ["line_total"]=>
      float(150)
      ["line_tax"]=>
      float(31.5)
      ["data"]=>
      object(WC_Product_Simple)#1251 (12) {
```

After `WC()->cart->cart_contents` I don't know how to get `'line_subtotal'` value.

May I need to convert this object to something else before trying to get any value?

Comment: may I see the whole object?

Comment: Convert your object to array then you can easily access the data, like this. $data = json_encode(json_decode($objects)); print_r($data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
foreach(WC()->cart->cart_contents as $cart_content) {
    echo $cart_content['line_subtotal']
}
```

using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) since the value of "cart_contents" is array.